# Remove all text in between div tags (including the tags)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am looking for the best way to remove all of the text in between 2 div tags, including the tags themselves.

For example:

```
<body>
<div id="spacer"> This is a title </div>
</body>
```

becomes:

```
<body>
</body>
```

Edit:  This needs to happen on the server side (C#)

Comment: Are you doing this server or client side?

Comment: `$('#spacer').remove();`

Comment: Client-side or server-side, it all comes down to rendering HTML. Are you injecting the contents as `partials`? Is it just a pure `view`? So many possibilities and tons of ways to accomplish this.

Comment: @DennisRongo he said server side but, yeah, is missing all the details that would help determine how to hide it.

Comment: Deleted my answer since it is in server side

Comment: What if  there are divs inside the div?  Remove those too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this lib: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ to manipulate on the server side, below is example for your case:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml("<body><div id=\"spacer\"> This is a title </div></body>");
doc.GetElementbyId("spacer").Remove();

var stream = new StringWriter();
doc.Save(stream);

var result = stream.ToString();
```

**Edit:**

You also can use xpath to select any nodes you want:

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("body/div");
nodes.ToList().ForEach(node => node.Remove());
```

Comment: @MikeSmithDev: this is a third party to allow us manipulating on Html

Comment: This is really cool, but I need the ability to select any div element, not just id "spacer"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but best way to hide or remove detail on fly in your case would be JQuery/Javascript since you are not refering to server side control.

In case you are just parsing string:-

1)Parse and find first occurance/last occurance and trim things in between.

2)XML parsing would be other way and a better one I guess because you can iterate throughout the xml to manipulate in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

you can use regular expression to strip html tags and text. You will find several examples in google.